# How to define response error metadata in swagger/swashbuckle WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I have figured out how to create response object metadata in swashbuckle:

```
[Route("X/{Y:Guid}")]
[HttpGet]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Bla", typeof(BlaDto))]
public IHttpActionResult GetSomething([FromUri] Guid someGuid)
{
    Bla returnObject;
    try
    {
        returnObject = _service.Get(someGuid);
    }
    catch (DatabaseException databaseException)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("DatabaseException", databaseException.Message);
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    return Ok(returnObject);     
}
```

I am  still looking for examples to define request object meta data and meta data for 400 errors etc. Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object metadata of an operation is detected by Swashbuckle automatically. Object metadata of errors can be specified by adding more `SwaggerResponseAttribute`s.

Here's an example:

```
[Route("X}")]
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, "Bla", typeof(BlaDto))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, Type = typeof(ErrorResponse))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(ErrorResponse))]
public IHttpActionResult CreateBla(BlaDto bla)
{
    BladDto returnObject;

    try
    {
        returnObject = _service.Create(bla);
    }
    catch (DatabaseException databaseException)
    {
        var error = new ErrorResponse { Message = databaseException.Message);
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error);
    }
    catch (SomeOtherException ex)
    {
        var error = new ErrorResponse { Message = ex.Message);
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, error);
    }
    return Ok(returnObject);     
}

public class ErrorResponse
{
    string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you telling, that I can’t use ‘return BadRequest(ModelState);’ and see swagger response example?